# How can I access admin console from WebSphere Liberty server?

Tags: java, server, websphere, websphere-liberty

How can I access admin console for Websphere Liberty ? I searched on google and I found this url : http://localhost:9080/adminCenter/ but it gives me : Context Root Not Found.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, you need to install (`bin/installUtility install adminCenter-1.0`) and enable (`<feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>`) the adminCenter-1.0 feature on your server, as well as enable https & a user registry (to login with).

You can find detailed instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_ui_setup.html